# Usar o id para uma inserção sem auto incremento

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

No `MYSQL` tenho uma tabela de inscritos onde a chave primária é o número de inscrição que é uma coluna que não possui auto-incremento, eu não posso mudar isso. Eu fiz, em Codeigniter, um método que pega o próximo id para inserção assim:

```
SELECT MAX(incricao)+1 AS inscricao FROM inscritos;
```

Isso é feito na inserção mesmo, eu já tenho o objeto pronto, então coloco esse valor no objeto e insiro no banco de dados e funciona.

A questão é se existe uma forma se fazer isso durante a inserção usando o codeigniter mesmo, php ou sql. 
Se não houver, fazendo isso que citei eu corro o risco de duas inscrições simultâneas pegarem o mesmo número de inscrição?

Comment: Se de qualquer forma você está manualmente incrementando numericamente em 1, não vejo porque não usar auto-increment do banco. E sim, da forma que você está fazendo você vai ter problema de conflito de keys sim. Qual a razão de não usar o do banco?

Comment: O banco de dados é de uma escola, essa tabela é usada por outras aplicações, então não me permitiram alterá-la.

Comment: Como você não pode alterar a tabela existente, crie então uma tabela só para o auto_increment e obtenha o ID assim: `SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'nome_table_incrementadora'
AND table_schema = DATABASE( ) ;`

Comment: Ou `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'nome_table_incrementadora'`

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que uma solução interessante neste caso seria criar um Trigger no banco de dados. Assim, seria possível definir que antes de inserir um novo registro, pegue o próximo valor disponível e utilize-o como ID.

Por exemplo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerIncrementInscritos BEFORE INSERT ON inscritos
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.incricao = SELECT MAX(incricao)+1 AS inscricao FROM inscritos;
END
```

Ou seja, criar um gatilho (create trigger) antes de inserir na tabela inscritos (BEFORE INSERT ON inscritos), para cada linha inserida (no caso só terá uma) o campo inscricao do novo registro (NEW.inscricao) será o max de inscricao + 1.

Answer (score 0):

No Codeigniter existe o método `$this->db->insert()` que retorna o `ID` do último registro inserido no banco de dados.

Esse método retorna exatamente o último `ID` inserido, pois ele usa a função `last_insert_id()` do `MySQL`, assim fazendo com que não tenha o erro de inscrições simultâneas pegando o mesmo id.

```
$data = array(
    'nm_contato' => $this->input->post('txt_nm_contato'),
    'nm_razao_social' => $this->input->post('txt_nm_razao_social'),
    'nm_fantasia' => $this->input->post('txt_nm_fantasia'),
    'nm_holding' => $this->input->post('txt_nm_holding'),
    'ds_email_contato' => $this->input->post('txt_ds_email_contato'),
    'cd_telefone' => $this->input->post('txt_cd_telefone'),
    'ds_inscricao_estadual' => $this->input->post('txt_ds_inscricao_estadual'),
    'ds_inscricao_municipal' => $this->input->post('txt_cli_cliente_ds_inscricao_municipal'),
);

$this->db->insert('tb_cliente', $data);
echo $this->db->insert_id();
```

Obs.: Esse método pode ser usando tanto no Codeigniter 2 quanto no 3.